# Determine if a point is within a large number of polygons

Tags: polygon, computational-geometry, raycasting, point-in-polygon

I'm aware of a ray casting methodology, however, this doesn't work for situated points along vertices and it only tests for the inclusion of a point inside of one polygon.

Is there a better way to do this other than just iterating the ray casting methodology along every polygon?

Thoughts and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: In what way is this too broad ?

Answer (score 0):

If preprocessing of the polygon set is not allowed, you can't do much better than exhaustive testing.

Otherwise, you can use a point location data structure to speed-up the queries.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_location